# android : retrofit calling post throws postbody required

Tags: android, post, retrofit

How to call retrofit with post parameters. am getting following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: method POST must have a request body.
```

source declaration

```
@POST("/oauth/token")
void userAccessToken(@Query("grant_type") String grant_type,
                     @Query("username") String username,
                     @Query("password") String password,
                     Callback<AutorizationData> callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

`POST` is method which requires `@Body` annotation in request.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known [issue](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/854) in OkHttp. You can and some empty stub body to avoid this error

Answer (score 0):

You need to call it this way:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/oauth/token")
void userAccessToken(
@Field("grant_type") String grant_type,
@Field("username") String username,
@Field("password") String password,
Callback<AutorizationData> callback);
```